# Mulesoft XML Accessing Schema Documentation

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, mulesoft, mule4

I'm trying to build mule 4 XML file validation. In order to do that i'm trying to access the xsd file for the Database connector using the following link: http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd. But I'm getting 502 (Bad Gateway) error.

May I know how do we access this XSD file? Is there somewhere we have to register ourselves or something?

[image: Mule 4 XML File]

Answer (score 0):

The XSD files for Mule Runtime and Mule connectors are inside the jars of the plugin, not published in the web. There is no documented way to do this.